# Any way to hack FogBugz On demand to SSO?

Tags: django, single-sign-on, fogbugz-on-demand

I will launch soo a new iPhone app and want to off-load the forums to my actual FogBugz On Demand account.

However, I discover that FOD have no facility to integrate Single sing-on. I use django and have the option to use open-id, but not know if exist a way to make this happend.

Obviously, I could hack a simple forums like the one on FogBugz in django or reuse one, but I just think that aintegrated forum with the bug tracking is the best thing.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

FogBugz On Demand now natively includes some authentication methods other than the standard username/password authentication.

Setting up authentication with Google's OAuth is quite simple for companies using Google Apps for work email. Once an administrator enables OAuth following the instructions in [this article](http://help.fogcreek.com/11398/enabling-fogbugz-authentication-with-google-oauth) on Fog Creek Software's help site, logging in is as simple as clicking the OAuth button on the login page. All of the users' settings are retained.

If you’re already managing the rest of your authentication through a SAML 2.0 provider, you can also use your identity provider for FogBugz login. Steps for configuring SSO can be found in [this article](http://help.fogcreek.com/11517/saml-single-sign-on-in-fogbugz). This requires a bit more configuration than OAuth, but will work for companies that don't use Google Apps for email.

Of course, if you have any questions about configuring SSO in FogBugz, you can always contact customer support at http://www.fogcreek.com/contact/.

Answer (score 0):

From the FogBugz forum:

```
http://support.fogcreek.com/default.asp?fogbugz.4.102256.3
```

I believe this is you there also.  The answer provided shouldn't be too difficult to implement.

Comment: Yeah, I forget to add the link to the discussion.

But I haven't found about BugMonkey (how is used that???)

Comment: You may want to contact the author Michael Pryor.  His details are on this discussion page: http://support.fogcreek.com/default.asp?fogbugz.4.97697.7

The actual plug-in:
http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/plugins/plugin.aspx?ixPlugin=16

Comment: note that the old forums are not maintained. This post is on the current support Q&A site: http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/questions/414/does-fogbugz-support-single-sign-on (I work in support at Fog Creek, write us with any questions: customer-service@fogcreek.com)